# addView() add the view but it is not showed

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created an adapter for a Spinner that looks like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private LinearLayout llContainer;

public MyAdapter (Context context, List<String> names) {
    super(context, 0, filters);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);
    }

    llContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String name = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.some_layout_drop, parent, false);
    }

    Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setText(name);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        void onClick(View v){
            addItemToLinearLayout();
        }
    })

    return convertView;
}

private void addItemToLinearLayout(){
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("something");
    btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ));

    //HERE I ADD A BUTTON TO THE LINEAR LAYOUT llContainer
    llContainer.addView(btn);

}
```

}

The problem is that the button is not showed in the linearLayout. Does the fact that the llContainer is assigned in getView() method has something to do with this ? If I manually add a button in the llContainer via/from XML he shows up.

To clarify the question: I have a spinner view. What I want is when I click it the dropdown shall contains some buttons. When I click one of those buttons on the spinner view(the portion that display what value user picked) to add a button or a textview or something. If I try to debug the application the llContainer contains the added view but it's seems that the mMeasuredHeight and mMeasuredWidth are 0 and also the id is 0 and the coordonates are 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn = new Button(); //without context?
```

maybe something like

```
Button btn = new Button(context); //pass context into the function
```

in [android.widget.Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) :

> Public Constructors

```
Button(Context context)
Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

Comment: Yeah. My code is much more complicated then that but when I posted it I typed it generalizing. I solved the problem doing this: 
`if(llContainer == null) {llContainer == blablabla; }` The thing is why this is working ? I supose that getView method is called more than once. But why that ?

Comment: getView(...) method is called for each item/view in your Spinner/ ListView etc